# How can I transfer the mouse position on the Canvas to the Ruler?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application with Canvas and a Ruler. Now I need to pass Canvas OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) to the Ruler to reflect mouse movements on its scale. Both controls are created independently while initialization, they do not know of each other. How can I transfer the mouse position on the Canvas to the Ruler?

Answer (score 0):

MouseEventArgs has a [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx) methos that allows you to pass any IInputElement as parameter, and returns the position of the mouse pointer relative to the specified element. Pass your Ruler as parameter value.

Comment: Thank you for help, but you forgot that my controls are not linked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I still have doubts. It seems to me a bit complicated:

1. Canvas as a "parent" control contains this piece of code:

   public Point MousePosition
       {
           get { return (Point)GetValue(MousePositionProperty); }
           set { SetValue(MousePositionProperty, value); }
       }

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MousePositionProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("MousePosition", typeof(Point), typeof(DesignerCanvas), new UIPropertyMetadata(point));

   protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnMouseMove(e);
       MousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
   ```

   }
2. The Ruler contains the following code:

   public Point Position
       {
           get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
           set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
       }

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(HorizontalRuler), new UIPropertyMetadata(defaultMousePoint,
         new PropertyChangedCallback(PositionPropertyChangedCallback)));

   private static void PositionPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       HorizontalRuler horizontalRuler = (HorizontalRuler)sender;
       horizontalRuler.InvalidateVisual();
   }
   ```